# Visualizing values in a normalized plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization

I have some data that I would like to plot, visualizing in a normalized chart.
Dataset:

```
            Gini
    var1    0.000223
    var2    0.000047
    var3    0.000933
    var4    0.000081
    var5    0.000014

df.sort_values(by='Gini', ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

I have tried with `plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 1))` but this just changes the scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're having a single column and plotting only the `"Gini"` column, you can select that column and normalize it before plotting it like:

```py
((df['Gini']-df['Gini'].min())/(df['Gini'].max()-df['Gini'].min())).sort_values().plot(kind='bar')
```

In general, you can normalize the whole dataframe and plot it:

```py
df_normalized = (df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
df_normalized.sort_values(by='Gini', ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
```